# VirtualBox using VBoxSVGA does not respond to keyboard or mouse

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, mouse, display-resolution

**Host:** Ubuntu 20.04

**Guest:** Ubuntu 22.04

**Virtualbox:**

- System: 4GB RAM
- Display: 256MB RAM
- Storage 25GB
- Graphics Controller: VBoxSVGA
- Acceleration: 3D
- Storage: (I have Guest Additions installed version 6.1.38)

When I change the Graphics Controller to VMSVGA and start the VM, my taskbar shows up, I can open apps, change the audio volume etc. However, when I set the GC to VBoxSVGA, the desktop loads up but the taskbar doesn't show and it doesn't take any input from the keyboard or mount (for example if I press CTRL+ALT+T, the terminal should popup but it doesn't) when I right click the desktop to see the menu for settings etc it doesn't show up.

I would just use VMSVGA because it works except that it stays stuck in 800x600  resolution which is unusable as I need more resolution that that.

Also, important to note that bidirectional copy/paste and drag and drop does not work at all.

Comment: *Host: Ubuntu 20.04* and the guest is...?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ubuntu 22.04 (I'll put that in the post)